# How to delete from match pattern in a specific column until end of file

Tags: awk, sed

I want to delete the records in a file once a pattern is found and delete all lines from that pattern until end of the file

I tried doing in awk but I haven't found if there is a simpler way to do it

So I want to match the pattern in the second column and then delete records from that pattern until the end of the file

```
awk -F"," '$2 ~ /100000/ {next} {print}'  file.csv
```

So the above code skips those lines however as you can see i need to add multiple match patterns to ignore lines after the ones that have the value 100000 in 2nd column are ignored. Please note that the values in 2nd column appear sequentially so after 100000 would come 100001 and there is no fixed end number.

Comment: Could you please post samples of input and expected output in your question and let us know then?

Comment: `values in 2nd column appear sequentially` just curious.. does your 2nd column goes `1,2,3,...` ? if so, you could use `head -n99999 file.csv`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I got your problem correctly IMHO I believe you need following.

```
awk '$2==100000{print;exit} 1' Input_file
```

This will print till the line whose 2nd column is 100000 and then since you don't want to print anything do in spite of simply reading further file and skipping it, this will exit from code which will additionally save our time too.

OR as per Ed Morton sir's nice suggestion:

```
awk '1; $2==100000{exit}' Input_file
```

Comment: @user3423407, Glad that it helped you, you could select this answer as correct one too, cheers.

Comment: `1` = `{print}`. Duplicated code (e.g. a `print` statement) is generally bad and you don't need to print from 2 locations `$2==100000{print;exit} {print}`, just put the print in the right place: `{print} $2==100000{exit}` or if you prefer to keep using `1` it'd be `1; $2==100000{exit}`

Comment: @EdMorton, Thank you sir, added that solution now  sir, cheers.